# Importance of Categorical variables in regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data, regression-coefficients

I am performing regression analyses in R and want to test several categorical variables consisting of more than ten classes. For example, University of graduation, profession, city, etc. The goal is to define income per year. By doing regression analysis, I get that some coefficients that characterize the importance of these variables (for example, profession is more important than a city of living).

In addition, I need to analyze which profession is more important and graduates of which university could get a bigger income. For example, lawyers from Stanford. How can I do this? How to define the most profitable professions?

I’m a newbie in Data Science and would be really grateful for any help!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Data science can’t do this. You need econometrics. And this starts with reading the literature in the field. People are looking at this and you will save a lot of time by not stepping in the common traps. Study the research methods applied in this area

Comment: @Aksakal At this point data science is just a massive umbrella term and I would say that it is appropriate to classify this as a data science problem. Econometrics is a way more specific field but if you are doing linear regression then you are doing machine learning and you can classify it as data science IMO.

Comment: @Tylerr data scientists are not known for causal inference studies, which OP is thinking about. Running regressions is easy, it’s not easy to establish directional relationships. Most importantly I saw many papers on similar subjects in economics: education and income etc, it makes sense to see what’s been done before running regressions

Answer (score 1):

In regression analysis, the only was to use categorical variables as covariates is by splitting them up into binary categories (e.g., instead of one variable with universities as categories, multiple binary variables for each university). In R this can be very simply achieved by turning the categorical variable to a `Factor`:

```
data <- data.frame(salary = c(100,100,120,150,160,170,60,70,80),
                   university = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"))
data$university <- as.factor(data$university)
summary(lm(salary~university, data))


Call:
lm(formula = salary ~ university, data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-10.000  -6.667   0.000  10.000  13.333 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  106.667      6.086  17.527 2.21e-06 ***
universityb   53.333      8.607   6.197 0.000814 ***
universityc  -36.667      8.607  -4.260 0.005320 **
```

Remember, with dummy variables, the coefficients represent the difference between said category and the reference category. In this example, university B graduates, on average, make 53K more than graduates of university A (the reference category).
Note that you can change the reference category using `relevel` function:

```
data$university <- relevel(data$university, ref = 2)
```

This will take care of the first step. However, with multiple categorical variables with many categories, this will quickly become cumbersome. You might be well served by trying to decide, empirically or theoretically, to clump categories together - Ivy League, STEM, Humanities etc.. This will become even more important in the final step.

What you wish to do is create interaction terms. Interactions are a way of looking at the combined effect of the intersection of two (or more) variables (such as Layers from Stanford). Note, however, that having many interactions between *all* categories might soon become unwieldy - if you interact 20 categories with 20 categories you will end up with 361 interactions. Here, too, you can look at different interactions and using some logic choose several that make the most sense. In theory, if you do not care *at all* about legibility, you can use all interactions, but this will be overfitting and will likely kill significance.

Comment: I would like to add to this great answer that each parameter you estimate 'costs' a degree of freedom. This is relevant to the last part of the answer, because yes, including all these interactions and dummy variables for your categories will eat up a lot of degrees of freedom and may lead to overfitting, but this may not be an issue if you have a really big sample. What constitutes a 'really big sample' is complicated, this depends at least on the amount of parameters to be estimated and to what extent your data is collinear.